# UTF-16 Charecter Printing in JAVA

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16

I have to print **UTF-16** character in text box of javafx but this code only prints reference.

```
new WriteThreadServer(table, "\tU+1F601".getBytes().toString(),main);
```

second parameter of the function is saved ina string then  printed using `textbox.settext()`.

Comment: What do you expect it to print, and what does it print instead? Do you need [`\t\uD83D\uDE01`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f601/index.htm) instead?

Comment: I think you want to convert bytes in in UTF-16 to string. If that is the case use ---- new String(bytes, "UTF-16"); ----

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to print a tab, then a ''GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES', you'd need to use:

```
new WriteThreadServer(table, "\\t\uD83D\uDE01",main);
```

You are currently:

- Taking a string literal
- Converting it to a byte array using your JVM's default charset
- Calling `toString()` on the array, resulting in `[B@106d69c`, or similar.

If you want unicode characters in your string, you need to provide them in the required format. Sites like [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f601/index.htm) provide the "C/C++/Java source code" representation.

Comment: Now it is not  showing reference but it is showing a box. Can you help me about this?

Comment: You need to use a font which actually provides a glyph for the thing you are trying to display. A box is displayed when no such glyph exists.

Answer (score 0):

`U+1F601` denotes a Unicode code point. It does not fit a single UTF-16 char (16 bits). It also will not automatically be converted; the preceding `\t` is just a tab char.

This kind of Unicode is written a bit cumbersome:

```
String s = new String(new int[] { 0x1F601 }, 0, 1);
```

Or with the preceding tab character `'\t'`:

```
String s = new String(new int[] { '\t', 0x1F601 }, 0, 2);

String s = "\t" + new String(Character.toChars(0x1F601));
```

In java String holds Unicode, as array of char, UTF-16. You can then do a `setText(s)`. Mind that the used font must be able to display that code point. A full Unicode font might do, like MS Arial Unicode. These fonts easily measure 35 MB.